# Make hide not disable all folders and .tmp files except pdf files (contaned in that folders)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to **make hide not disable** all child folders and .tmp files (below) and show only .pdf files to user,
my directory structure composed of **dynamically created** (that prevents me of editng in .htaccess for new folder names) child folders like:

```
Parent->
  Child1->
  Child1.tmp,Child1.pdf

  Child2->
  Child2.tmp,Child2.pdf

  and so on...
```

as you can see above disabling folders will cause *access denied* to pdf files.
Thus when user creates folder named F1 and upload pdf file, then a new child folder named F1 containing that pdf file + .tmp file of same name as pdf are created, further when any user wants to search and  download that public pdf file, he should see only (and access only) that .pdf file not the folder in which it exists and not the tmp.
So is there any **secure way** of doing that (specially using .htaccess).??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/my_project/i/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_project/i/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/.+?\.tmp|/)$ - [F,NC]
```

Make sure to make this your first rule.

Comment: Right but `/my_project/i/ChildFolder1/i.pdf` can still be accessed